# importxml not selecting element in span google sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, import, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I am trying to scrape prices off the Lowe's website but don't think I've been able pinpoint the right xpath for the importxml or I'm just doing it completely wrong.

The URL for ref:

```
 https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=pliers
```

=importxml(https://www.lowes.com..., xpath)

I've tried `//span[@class='h5 js-price']]` and the

`//*[@id="product-1115091"]/div/div[2]/div/span` xpaths but kept getting an "#N/A" error. Basically just trying to get all prices to spit out.

Answer (score 0):

```
//span[contains(@class, 'js-price')]
```

this is the price tag :

```
<span class="h5 js-price">$13.98</span>
```

you can use `contains()` function in the `@class` attribute to find the `span` tag

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it reads the span tag as if there was nothing in there. I've tried stepping through each block of code to the span class but it outputs -please put in your zip code.

Also, tried going into the product page to get the price, but to the same result. 

https://www.lowes.com/pd/CHANNELLOCK-10-in-Tongue-and-Groove-Pliers/1115091
<span itemprop="price" content="14.97"></span>